# the audio device "default" could not be used: no such file or directory

Tags: audio, stream, media-player, vlc, mininet

I tried to stream video on mininet by using VLC media player and aftering I started to stream , an error occurs on my receiver host: "the audio device "default" could not be used: no such file or directory."
How can I fix this .THX

How can I get my video streaming

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a minimal setup that reproduces the problem? If you're using a VM what does the audio setup look like? Also if you're not watching the video have you tried running it without sound by default?

Comment: Oh ! I is it because I run the mininet on the Linux server by using mobaxterm.
I don't use a VM to run my mininet . Is that a reason Why I can't play the video ?
But I can see the "picture" of my video on my VLC-media-player

Comment: I would suspect so but as I said, need a reproducible example if I were to be more helpful

Comment: After using VM , it can work ! Thanks a lot bro

Comment: Glad I could help, consider accepting and or upvoting the answer so people can find it easier in future if they have similar issues.